# Shared memory error while connecting to Oracle

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

I get this error message each time I try to connect to my Oracle XE local database under Ubuntu 15.10 :

```
user@user-X220:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu May 5 20:58:13 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYS
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I have read on some forums that i have to delete my /dev/shm repository :

```
 sudo rm -rf /dev/shm
 sudo mkdir /dev/shm
 sudo mount -t tmpfs shmfs -o size=2048m /dev/shm
```

I tried actually to do that but it seems that `/dev/shm` is used by several processors including my firefox navigator.

Any help will more than welcome.

Comment: ORA-27101 generally means that your database is down... also, sys needs to connect as sysdba: admin$ sqlplus sys as sysdba  *connected to an idle instance*   startup open;

Comment: Whats the value of `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are some hoops with fire you need to jump thru for installing Oracle XE on Ubuntu. You may want to try following the article here: http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

Oracle is very finicky when it comes to installing on particular OS's. It's very specific as to what they support. However, that doesn't mean you can't install it on any OS you want. You'll just need to jump thru a few hoops... Some with fire.

Hope it helps!